Convolution of a bounded function and measures
Given a function $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and a family of Radon measure $\mu_\alpha$, under what condition do we have $f*\mu_\alpha$ equi-continuous?
One condition I know is if $\mu_\alpha$ has a density $g_\alpha$, where $|g_\alpha| \leq g$ and $g\in L^1$, then this property holds. This is a result of Lemma 4.1 in Luis Caffarelli and Luis Silvestre, Regularity theory for fully nonlinear integrodifferential
equations (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.4681).
My question is what is the equivalent condition one can impose without using the existence of such densities?
A related post is Convolution of a continuous function and a finitely additive measure.

For the convolution $f\ast\mu_\alpha$ to be well defined for any $f\in L^\infty$  it is natural to assume  that $\mu_\alpha$ has a density since  a modification of $f$ on a Lebesgue negligible set could change the result. (E.g.,  $\mu_\alpha$  could be a Dirac measure.)  Then try to understand why $f\ast\mu$ is continuous  if $f\in L^\infty$ and $\mu$ has a density  and then try  to control its modulus of continuity in terms  of $f$ and $\mu$.  It would be hard to dramatically improve  the result of Caffarelli and Silvestre.

@Sean A bit of clarification would help: Do you really mean $f$ to be a function, or is it a class of functions equivalent w.r.t. Haar measure? As pointed out by Liviu N, in either case the convolution with an arbitrary Radon measure is not well defined.

I meant $f$ is a function, and the Radon measure $\mu$ has some minimal regularity regarding the Levy type. Would that be sufficient?
